# Database Design for current and historical pricing of multiple products

Tags: database-design, relational-database

What would be the the ideal design for the following ?

Current price of fuel
Discounted price (Not fixed, published along with the current price )
Historical price of each and every fuel (for graphing/historical query)

What I've have in mind is :

Product_table

- product_id (pkey)
- product_name
- product_brand

Current_price

- product_id
- site_price
- discounted_price
- created_date

History_price

- product_id
- site_price
- discounted_price
- created_date

Data is populated via web crawling/parsing of data sources.

Current_price & history_price looks exactly the same and should the logic to determine the current_price be offloaded to application layer?

Answer (score 0):

You already have your design. But not two price tables -- just one. Take a look at the query structure that will return the data and historic price of a particular product at a particular time:

```
select  p.ID, p.Name, p.Brand, pr.SitePrice, pr.DiscountedPrice
from    Products p
join    Prices   pr
    on  pr.ProductID = p.ID
    and pr.EffDate   =(
        select  Max( pr1.EffDate )
        from    Prices pr1
        where   pr1.ProductID = pr.ProductID
            and pr1.EffDate <= :DateOfInterest )
where   p.ID = :ProductOfInterest;
```

This will return one row of output with the information of a product (:ProductOfInterest) and the price information that was in effect at the specified time (:DateOfInterest). However, if you place the current datetime value into :DateOfInterest, the *current* price information is returned.

So you can have all prices, past and present, in one table and query historic *and* current data with the same query. In fact, drop the `where` clause and hard code the current timestamp into a view and you now have a data source that returns only current prices.

```
create view CurrentPrices as
select  p.ID, p.Name, p.Brand, pr.SitePrice, pr.DiscountedPrice
from    Products p
join    Prices   pr
    on  pr.ProductID = p.ID
    and pr.EffDate   =(
        select  Max( pr1.EffDate )
        from    Prices pr1
        where   pr1.ProductID = pr.ProductID
            and pr1.EffDate <= Now()
        );
```

Now your query for current price information for a particular product is simpler:

```
select  *
from    CurrentPrices
where   ID = :ProductOfInterest;
```

At this time, we can't pass parameters into views, so the view can't be used to look back in time. But that's not a particularly large disadvantage when you see what you can get. You can, however, create a view that matches all prices to show the price history:

```
create view HistoricPrices as
select  p.ID, p.Name, p.Brand, hp.SitePrice, hp.DiscountedPrice, pr.EffDate
from    Products p
join    Prices   pr
    on  pr.ProductID = p.ID;
```

For this query, you would, of course, want to expose the effective date. Then the query to get the complete price history of a product:

```
select  *
from    HistoricPrices
where   ID = :ProductOfInterest
order by EffDate;
```